# Calculate speed using proximitiy sensor of Android

Tags: java, android, sensors, proximity

How can I calculate the speed of my hand when I move it close to the proximity sensor of Android?
I mean how i calcul how much the time you put you hand in the sensor with ms not second

--------- EDIT: 

I mean when i put my finger above the sensor it's will start counting and when i take my hand it's will stop!

Comment: what? please, make a complete question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Speaking about camera, this is very broad question. A lot of math will be involved.

Comment: you don't understand me
i want to check time when you put you move your hand up of the sensor 
i mean how mush (ms) you put you hand in the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a proximity sensor on most Android smartphones. What you may be referencing is the [light sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_LIGHT) on the front of the device (usually the screen blacks out on calls when you put it to your face).

The close you get to this sensor, the more light you block. It is one way to tell proximity but probably won't offer the accuracy you would like. You could technically sense the speed in the change of this light value, but it will be rough at best.

Another option would be to use image recognition, and the front facing camera however, I have never toyed with this feature before thus cannot offer you suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Fred L
 
So i know what i do, now i just wanna count the time when you put your hand up of sensor, 
I mean when i put my finger above the sensor it's will start counting and when i take my hand it's will stop, i hope you understand me

Comment: Yes I understand. Count the time the sensor is covered. The light sensor will definitely do this, and accurately too. Best of luck!